# Preventing Screenshots and Screen Recording on Website written in React

Tags: reactjs, cloudflare, privacy, drm

I have videos stored on Cloudflare and am streaming them to my React website using Stream : https://github.com/cloudflare/stream-react

I want to prevent screen recording and screenshots when the videos are being played. How do i do this? This is one of the biggest requirements I have since I'll be broadcasting content related to yoga on the website and do not want subscribers to screen record and use it later without a subscription.

I have seen a bunch of articles on DRM and DRM Players and have tried reaching out to Google Widevine but they haven't replied and I'm in the dark about what I should be doing.

Any resources, solutions you may have implemented, any guidance will be extremely helpful! Thank you.